# Extract a string of numbers (of varying length) from the middle of a larger string in r

Tags: r, tidyverse

I've seen a bunch of similar questions (and I got some ideas from them), but I can't seem to get my code to work properly. I'm using R.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~name, ~employment, 
  "Markisha", "{'url': 'https://api.zenefits.com/core/people/123/employments', 'object': '/meta/ref/list', 'ref_object': '/core/employments'}",
  "Rickisha", "{'url': 'https://api.zenefits.com/core/people/1234/employments', 'object': '/meta/ref/list', 'ref_object': '/core/employments'}"
)
```

I would like to extract the numbers between the words "People" and "employments" in the "employment column. The outcome would look like this.

```
correct_df <-tribble(~name, ~employment_id
                     "Markisha", "123", 
                     "Rickisha", "1234"
                     )
```

I've attempted to use this code chunk

```
str_match(employment, "people/(.*?)/employments"
```

but my results look like this

```
incorrect_df <- tribble(
  ~name, ~employment, ~employment_id, 
  "Markisha", "{'url': 'https://api.zenefits.com/core/people/123/employments', 'object': '/meta/ref/list', 'ref_object': '/core/employments'}", "people/123/employments",
  "Rickisha", "{'url': 'https://api.zenefits.com/core/people/1234/employments', 'object': '/meta/ref/list', 'ref_object': '/core/employments'}", "people/1234/employments"
)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex lookaround in `str_extract` to extract the one or more digits (`\\d+`) that succeeds the 'people/`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  transmute(name, employment_id = str_extract(employment, '(?<=people/)\\d+'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  name     employment_id
#   <chr>    <chr>        
#1 Markisha 123          
#2 Rickisha 1234
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's no other digits in the string this will do; if here are you will need to define the context on the left and/or the right of the digits in question using lookaround, as suggested by @akrun:

```
library(stringr)
df$num <- str_extract(df$employment, "\\d+")
df
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  name     employment                                                                                                                      num  
  <chr>    <chr>                                                                                                                           <chr>
1 Markisha {'url': 'https://api.zenefits.com/core/people/123/employments', 'object': '/meta/ref/list', 'ref_object': '/core/employments'}  123  
2 Rickisha {'url': 'https://api.zenefits.com/core/people/1234/employments', 'object': '/meta/ref/list', 'ref_object': '/core/employments'} 1234
```